# MIPS code to sum an artithmetic series

Tags: mips

I have to write a MIPS code to sum the series 1 + 5 + 9 + ... + N, under the constraint that I should use minimum number of registers to implement the MIPS code.

Here's my solution. It'd would be nice if you could point out any mistakes.

```
High-level code:

    int count  = 1;
    int sum   = 1;

    while(count<N){
        count = count + 4;
        sum   = sum + count;
    }

Associate variable 'count' with register $t0 and
          variable 'sum'   with register $s0.

Equivalent MIPS code:

      addi $t0, $zero, 1
      addi $s0, $zero, 1

Loop: slti $t2, $t0,   N
      beq  $t2, $zero, Exit
      addi $t0, $t0, 4
      addi $s0, $s0, $t0
      j    Loop                  

Exit:
```

Comment: Well, you're not saving the sum anywhere that I can see...?

Comment: I've saved the sum in $s0 now. This was an exam assignment and my lecturer simply used the variable N without any mention of whether we ought to take N as a function parameter, so I am not really sure if my code is good since 'N', by itself, does not mean anything in MIPS assembly language.

Comment: You're counting $s0 `1, 5, 9, ... N`, but you're not saving the sum `1 + 5 + 9 + ... + N` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That was a subtle mistake!

Comment: Would you say it's good now? :)

Comment: Well, an N value of 3 will add up 1+5 as far as I can see since the comparison is done before adding 4 to $t0. Since in the first iteration, $t0=1, it's less than 3 and it'll add up 1+5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a register to save the actual sum. If N is hard coded, I'd do something like this (untested code);

```
    addi $t0, $zero, 0     ; Sum
    addi $t1, $zero, 1     ; Counter

Loop: 

    slti $t2, $t1, N + 1   ; Exit if $t1 > N
    beq  $t2, $zero, Exit
    add  $t0, $t0, $t1     ; $t0 = $t0 + $t1
    addi $t1, $t1, 4       ; $t1 += 4
    j    Loop                  

Exit:                      ; $t0 contains the sum here
```